# Sql Reporting Services and Javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, service, reporting

I am creating a site with bootstrap and javascript with nodejs Rest Api, but i need show a Report from sql Reporting Service with authentication credentials (username and password). What is the best way to show the report? and How i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can access a report from the JavaScript program using an URL.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/access-report-server-items-using-url-access